# HSlider as player seek time

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air

How can I convert the hslider data format from decimal into an H:M:S?

Answer (score 1):

Set the dataTipFormatFunction property of the HSlider to a function that converts seconds to h:m:s

you can set the maximum property to the duration property of your player to get the length in seconds